# Confluent Elasticsearch Sink connector, write.method : "UPSERT" on different key

Tags: elasticsearch, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, upsert

In COnfluent Elasticsearch Sink connector, I am trying to write in same Elasticsearch index from two different topics. First topic is INSERT and another topic is UPSERT. For UPSERT, I want to update the JSON document based on some other field instead of "_id". IS that possible ? If yes, How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use key.ignore=false and use existing primary key columns as _id for each json document.